# Maven downloads JARS with HTML content

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven, which I'm using in IntelliJ IDEA (Maven 3) on Windows 10.

I'm working on small project for one game server. My pom.xml is looking like this: https://pastebin.com/svkcprnP

But the problem is that when I use 'package' target - it will download broken files. Those files cannot be opened by Java and when opened by text editor they are in fact HTML files.

```
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Marek\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Marek\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Marek\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Marek\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Marek\.m2\repository\org\bukkit\Craftbukkit\1.14.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT\Craftbukkit-1.14.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Marek\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\17.0.0\annotations-17.0.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Marek\.m2\repository\com\github\MilkBowl\VaultAPI\1.5\VaultAPI-1.5.jar; error in opening zip file
```

Files with extensions JAR, SHA1 and POM are the same size and all of them are HTML files. I have tried to change the extension to HTML, for example this is the HTML file from /com/google/guava opened in Chrome.

[image: html file opened in Chrome]

Anything I try to use from these artifacts in code shows as unresolved... example:

[image: unresolved classes]

I have tried to remove entire local repository (.m2 folder) and redownload everything again, here is full debug log: https://pastebin.com/PTz1Ry2n

Basically it is showing warnings like this:

```
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <!DOCTYPE but is 050da2db9640b4a9b651c7a13770b477d66147c4 for https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/spigot/repos/craftbukkit/browse/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.14.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/spigot/repos/craftbukkit/browse/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.14.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (23 KB at 20.7 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\Marek\.m2\repository\org\spigotmc\spigot-api\1.14.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT\resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.14.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in vault-repo (http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases)
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Users\Marek\.m2\repository\org\spigotmc\spigot-api\1.14.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-bukkit-repo.xml is invalid: expected = after attribute name (position: TEXT seen ...ey="_super" data-wrm-batch-type="context" data-initially-rendered>... @18:270) 
org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: expected = after attribute name (position: TEXT seen ...ey="_super" data-wrm-batch-type="context" data-initially-rendered>... @18:270)
```

My pom.xml is correct, I'm using repositories and artifacts as everyone else. But it doesn't work for me.

I have searched on the internet and here on the stackoverflow... but found nothing useful. Mostly these errors were caused by three things:

- Wrong repository used in pom.xml (but I have errors everywhere, not
  just one repo).
- Proxy connecting to somewhere else (I'm not behind proxy)
- Antivirus software blocking and corrupting downloads (I'm using only Windows Defender and I have stopped it before trying to redownload everything)

Comment: You should turn on checksum policy https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this might be that the following is not a Maven repository, but a regular web page. Try removing it and see if that helps.

```
<repository>
    <id>bukkit-repo</id>
    <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/spigot/repos/craftbukkit/browse</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! But I still don't understand why this entry ruined everything... why Maven choosed this repo for every artefact?

Comment: I assume it could be caused by the HTTP status codes that site sends. E.g. `https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/spigot/repos/craftbukkit/browse/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.14.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml` returns a 200 (= OK). If this happens for all of the requested resources, Maven likely thinks that this "repository" provides all of the artifacts.